# How to resolve "UndefVarError: consume not defined" in JULIA

Tags: julia

When I call consume(generator) I get this error. Is this a version problem?

```
function fib()
    a = 0
    produce(a)
    b = 1
    produce(b)
    while true
        a , b = b , a+b
        produce(b)
    end
end

generator = Task(fib)

consume(generator)
```

Comment: Looks like produce and consume are deprecated: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-replace-consume-and-produce-with-channels/5125

Comment: Not just deprecated, they're gone. As a general tip, if you're following outdated blog posts or the like, you can typically learn how to change your code to more modern patterns by running it in a version that deprecated the functionality. In this case, if you downloaded Julia 0.6 and ran your code, it would probably suggest how that should be written now. You can also check the `NEWS.md` for each release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a way to do something similar using a `Channel`

```
global channel = Channel{Int}(1)

function fib()
   # global here is not needed because we aren't modifying the channel handle, just the contents
   # global channel 
   a = 0
   put!(channel, a)
   b = 1
   put!(channel, b)
   while true
       a , b = b , a+b
       put!(channel,b)
       sleep(1)
   end
end

@async while true; item = take!(channel); println("item: $item"); end

@async fib()
```

Note that `@async` will hide errors, so you may want to do a `try catch` with `showerror(stderr, e, catch_backtrace())` if things are not running.

Each `@async` produces a `Task` handle.

Also the `put!` and `take!` will block when the channel if filled up.  You may want to expand the channel size to handle a larger buffer.